# Keras: Droupout with functional api in mlp

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

i am using du functional api from keras and would like to add a dropout to my multi layer perceptron.

do i have to put the dropout before or after the layer and do i have to connect the next layer to the dropout or to the previous layer?

```
hidden_Layer_2 = Dense(152,activation='relu')(hidden_Layer_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.4)(hidden_Layer_2)
hidden_Layer_3 = Dense(152, activation='relu')(hidden_Layer_2)
```

or

```
hidden_Layer_2 = Dense(152,activation='relu')(hidden_Layer_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.4)(hidden_Layer_2)
hidden_Layer_3 = Dense(152, activation='relu')(dropout_2 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is the right one. You always need to connect the layers in the order you want to use them.

```py
  hidden_Layer_2 = Dense(152,activation='relu')(hidden_Layer_1)
  dropout_2 = Dropout(0.4)(hidden_Layer_2)
  hidden_Layer_3 = Dense(152, activation='relu')(dropout_2 )
```